# Error 'incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8' due to 8-bit encoding of cookies (Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, ruby-1.9

I moved a web app that was using 1.8.7 to 1.9.2 and now I keep getting

```
incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

I have the database encoding to UTF-8 and I have also 'config.encoding = "utf-8"'.

I saw some ideas as possible workarounds and I added

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

But it didn't work either.

One specific chunk of code where I am getting this error is

```
%ul.address
- @user.address.split(',').each do |line|
  %li= line.titleize
```

I'm using HAML, I checked line.titleize, and the encoding is UTF-8. Seems that the template is being rendered with ASCII-8BIT and it gets screwed each time that I try to render characteres like 'ñ'

I'm working with Rails 3.0.5.

I have read the post by James Edward Gray, but I still can figure it out what is going on ;(.

I'd really appreciate any kind of help :D.

I also tried:

```
"string".force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

And

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Without any luck.

Fixed

---

See comments.

Comment: I've faced the same issue and it's usually a hidden string that's causing it. Let me ask you this, if you render without a layout (render :layout => false) and you remove all other code on the page except for the excerpt in your question, do you still get the same error?

Comment: Hey Pan, thanks! if I do render :layout => false, it doesn't throw the error.

Comment: Hey I just found where the problem was, I was using a value from the cookies in the template, turns out the cookies are ASCII-8BIT.
 
   cookies["location"].encoding
   #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>

That is what was causing all the issues, I did force_encoding('UTF-8') and that solved it.

Thanks Pan.

Comment: Glad I could help :) The HAML error lines are often not accurate.

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into something similar ... and found the fix hidden in the comments to this question, but think it is worth highlighting explicitly:

cookies are ASCII-8BIT but rails 3 templates are utf-8 by default. This means using a raw cookie value in a view may raise Encoding::CompatibilityError (if the user has an incompatible in the cookie value)

The fix (as noted by Adolfo Builes) is to coerce your cookie values to UTF-8, as in:

```
cookies["location"].force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

Answer (score -1):

for haml put

```
-# coding: UTF-8
```

line on the top left of the page.